# Epoch time with dot? 1391759952.7056

Tags: unix-timestamp

I'm using an API that returns "1391759952.7056" as a timestamp. I was wondering what the numbers behind the dot mean? As far as I know only 10 characters get used for Epoch time ...

Comment: Most likely fractions of seconds.

Comment: It's a number, it means what the numbers after a decimal normally mean in a floating point number.

Comment: Yes, I can see it's a number. I was wondering if it was a widely (or specific) used method - since I can only find examples that show 10 characters for Epoch time.

Comment: Java uses a time with milliseconds since the Epoch; it is often shown with 3 decimal places, but also shown with 13 digits (these days; it wasn't so long ago that the integer time stamps were only 9 digits (2001-09-09 was the switchover day).  Some systems provide 6 or even 9 digits after the decimal point; the `gettimeofday()` function provides µs resolution, and `clock_gettime()` provides ns resolution.

Comment: It could be one more reason to return "numbers behind the dot", than fractions of seconds: leap seconds, used for UTC and Earth rotation synchronization. Actually the number of seconds in a UTC day is not exactly 86400. Wikipedia gives some explanations about it.

Comment: What API? In what language? Is it returned as a string or as a floating-point number?

Answer (score 6):

If it were `1391759952.705 * 1000` it would be milliseconds. You seem to have one extra decimal! In Java, you would get this `(1391759952705)` with `System.currentTimeMillis()`. As a detail, in Java, the biggest range is given by `System.nanoTime() - nanoseconds` (faster than `currentMillis()` to my knowledge but not relative to a fixed point in time so it would be more suitable for measuring elapsed times, not the current time).

Answer (score 5):

Definitely fractions of a second, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

```
Run a couple of tests from the command line:
$ date -Ins -d@1452550837
2016-01-11T22:20:37,000000000+0000
$ date -Ins -d@1452550837.010
2016-01-11T22:20:37,010000000+0000
$ date -Ins -d@1452550837.000010
2016-01-11T22:20:37,000010000+0000
```

Tends to be inconvenient when parsing Unix times in Go.